# Non-existence of space with measure with following property

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I need to show that there is no such space $(\Omega , \Sigma , \mu)$ for which Every self-adjoint operator unitary equivalent to multiplication operator in $L_2 (\Omega , \mu)$. I think I just need some hints on attempting this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't this true when $\Omega$ is a finite set with counting measure (so that $L_2$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$)?  Do you want to exclude such finite dimensional examples?

Comment: I think , I want

Comment: "Every self-adjoint operator" on what space?  On a fixed Hilbert space? On $L^2(\Omega,\mu)$ itself?  On every separable Hilbert space?  On every Hilbert space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a self-adjoint operator $A$ with empty point spectrum.  Show that if $A$ is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator on $L^2(\Omega,\mu)$, then $(\Omega, \mu)$ contains no atoms.

Consider a rank-one orthogonal projection operator $P$.  Show that if $P$ is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator on $L^2(\Omega,\mu)$, then $(\Omega, \mu)$ contains an atom.

Comment: Orthogonal projection where ?

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO: Orthogonal projection onto a one-dimensional subspace.  That's what "rank one" means.

Comment: So I have just proved that if the space has got atom therefore point spectrum for multiplication operator on $L_2$ is non-empty. This means that $A$ has got non-empty point spectrum , right?

Comment: Sure, that's the contrapositive of the claim in the first paragraph.

Comment: And the second question. I get the idea of proof, but I can’t understand why we always can construct self-adjoint operator with empty point spectrum

Comment: And I can’t prove the second statement

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO: In $L^2([0,1])$, multiplication by $f(x)=x$ has empty point spectrum.  It follows that every infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space admits such an operator, since all such Hilbert spaces are unitarily isomorphic.  I am not sure offhand if this is true for non-separable spaces; if you want to cover them you may need a different idea.

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO: For the second statement: if $A$ is a set that is not an atom, show that there are at least two linearly independent functions supported on $A$ (indeed, they can have disjoint support).  Now if $P$ is unitarily equivalent to multiplication by a function $f$, then the subspace of $L^2(\Omega,\mu)$ which is supported on $\{f=1\}$ must map to the eigenspace of $P$ for $\lambda = 1$, which is one-dimensional.

Comment: If $H$ is not separable, it can be written as an (uncountable) orthogonal direct sum of infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert spaces $H_i$.  Let $P_i : H \to H_i$ be orthogonal projection.  For each $i$, let $A_i$ be a self-adjoint operator on $H_i$ with empty point spectrum, and let $A = \bigoplus_i A_i$.  Now if $Ax = \lambda x$ for some $x \ne 0$, then there exists $i$ with $P_i x \ne 0$, and we would have $A_i P_i x = P_i A x = \lambda P_i x$ which is absurd.  So $A$ also has empty point spectrum.